# How to move the stage within a class in Actionscript3?

Tags: class, actionscript, move, stage

Okay so I know how to move the stage within the actual .fla file by modifying this.x and this.y variables in the layer 1 actionscript.

But within the document class- public class Starlight extends MovieClip, it does not seem to work no matter what i try and my research lead me to this use code instead:

```
for( i = 0; i < stage.numChildren; i ++){
        stage.getChildAt(i).x -= player.speedx * player.bounceSpeed;
    stage.getChildAt(i).y -= player.speedy * player.bounceSpeed;
}
```

I do realize that its hacky and slower as compared to actually moving the stage itself. And i'm not sure what's going to happen if another object that moves comes into the stage because technically this code is unnaturally altering the x,y of everything in the stage.

Any help appreciated!! 
Cheers

Edit: Tried this--

```
    var stage2:Sprite = new Sprite();
        stage2.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        stage2.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        stage2.width = 4000;
        stage2.height = 4000;
        addChild(stage2);

        for (i = 1; i < 50; i ++)
        {
            var asteroid:Asteroid = new Asteroid();
            asteroid.x = Math.round(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth * 4);
            asteroid.y = Math.round(Math.random() * stage.stageHeight * 4);
            stage2.addChild(asteroid);
            collisionList.addItem(asteroid);
            asteroids.push(asteroid);
        }
```

Comment: What sort of result are you getting? An error, or nothing at all, or?..

Comment: the asteroids do not spawn at all and i cant collide into them with Player. If I remove the stage2 from addchild(asteroid) they will spawn.

Answer (score 1):

Woah, don't move the stage!

Create a `MovieClip` or a `Sprite` and stick everything in there, then it's just a case of moving that object.

```
var stage2:Sprite = new Sprite();

stage2.addChild(something);
stage2.addChild(somethingElse);

stage2.x = 10;
stage2.y = 10;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this and it doesnt work:
I'll edit my OP to the new code i tried.

Comment: Why are you multiplying the stageWidth by 4 *and* centering the container sprite?